# How I can send an String and an Integer over a socket?

Tags: java, sockets

I have 2 buttons in my client with a button listener each.

In my firt button listener I am sending a *String* over the socket and I am getting back an array of integers after it is spanwed. No problem there. Here is my code.

```
public void rollDice() {

    try {
        DataOutputStream sout1 = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        String line = "dice";
        PrintStream out1 = new PrintStream(sout1);
        out1.println(line);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

With the second listener I want t send first a *string* to put the server into the right state, and after I want to send an *integer* to continue the process. Here is my code but it doesn't seem to work. Server is printing a random number, even if I send a "2".

```
public void sendDice() {

    try {
        DataOutputStream sout2 = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        String line = "pick";
        PrintStream out2 = new PrintStream(sout2);
        out2.println(line);

        out2.write(diceListLength);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the server's side.

```
public void run() {

        boolean running = true;

        try {

            // Create streams for reading / writing lines of text to the socket
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            DataInputStream inputInt = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());

            ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

            // Print a message:
            System.out.println("\nClient from: " + s.getInetAddress() + " port " + s.getPort());

            while(running) {
                String st = input.readLine();

                if (st.equals("dice")) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < diceRolled.length - number; i++) {
                        diceRolled[i] = (int) ( 1 + Math.random() * 6);
                        System.out.print(diceRolled[i] + " ");
                    }
                    output.writeObject(diceRolled);
                    output.reset();
                } else if (st.equals("pick")) {
                    number = inputInt.readInt();
                    System.out.print(number);

                }
            } 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
         // Always be sure to close the socket
        } finally {
            try {
                if (s != null) {
                    System.out.println(s.getLocalSocketAddress() + " closed.");
                    s.close();
                }                   
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is `SocketInputStream` at server side?

Comment: @Nullpointer I am using `DataInputStream` but I didn't paste all the code. Updated.

Comment: Try printing the value of `st`..is it correct?

Comment: I'm guessing it doesn't know where to cut them apart in the input stream.

Comment: @Nullpointer yeah, I tested that. I used a `System.out.println("it works")` under my `else if` and I got it right into the server side.

Comment: No! just print the value of `st` and check what it contains!

Comment: @Nullpointer ok let me do that.

Comment: @Nullpointer the `System.out.print(st);` prints only *pick* and nothing else.

Comment: @Akumu a single integer will not be sent because of output buffering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting autoFlush on the PrintStream when you create it... a single integer will not be sent until newline or buffer full.

From [java's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)

> `autoFlush` - A boolean; if true, the output buffer will be flushed whenever a byte array is written, one of the println methods is invoked, or a newline character or byte ('\n') is written

**Also useful:**

1. Use line-based messaging, i.e. the second message type can be `"pick:4"` (check with `st.startsWith("pick")`) and then parse the integer. With your code, you can easily end up loosing state. (Single-line messages are "pseudo-atomic").
2. Don't create `DataInputStreams` in every listener method, make them object variables (same for PrintStreams...). There's no need to (re)create objects in every click.

Comment: Thanks for your reply man. I will read the documentation and I will test your method and I will approve your answer. I didn't know that I cannot send an single integer over a socket. Thanks very much for that.

Comment: Well, of course you CAN, but default settings in libraries will prevent you from doing that. Especially given the network traffic overhead from only sending 32bit of payload, 3-way handshakes and all that ;)

Comment: so you have to TELL it you WANT to do just that (via `autoFlush`). But again, I'd suggest concatenating the command with the integer and sending it in a single line (i.e. "`pick:4`", "`pick-4`", or even "`pick4`").